# linear algebra_proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying for linear algebra exam but I'm stuck with those two proofs:

1) suppose that $M$ is a matrix such that $U^t MU= D$, where $U$ is orthogonal and $D$ is diagonal. Show that $M M^t = M^t M$. Make sure to justify each step of your proof.

2) Suppose $N =M+ \alpha I$ , where $\alpha \in \mathbb C$. Given the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $N$, determine the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M$.

Please help me!

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1) Write $\;M=UDU^t\;$ , observing that $\;U^t=U^{-1}\;$ (orthogonal matrix)

2) Suppose $\;\lambda\;$ is an eigenvalue of $\;N\;$ with eigenvector $\;v\;$ , then

$$\lambda v=Nv=(M+\alpha I)v=Mv+\alpha v\implies Mv=(\lambda-\alpha) v$$